# Combinar 2 querys MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo estas 2 querys en `php` que las uso para mostrar una tabla, la primero agrupa todo los resultados por el `id` más grande registrado en la base, en base al campo u`nique_vendor_identifier` y la segunda query, suma el campo `payment` y lo agrupa en base al campo `unique_vendor_identifier` ignorando las entradas duplicadas que son exactamente iguales en todas sus filas.

Lo que quiero es juntar las 2 querys en una sola, o sea combinarlas, que la tabla siga mostrando agrupado por `unique_vendor_identifier` lo último de ese identificador en todos sus filas y a su vez que me muestre en el campo `payment` la suma del campo `payment` agrupada por `unique_vendor_identifier`.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM jsonapple 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM jsonapple GROUP BY unique_vendor_identifier)
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT payment, SUM(payment) 
FROM (SELECT unique_vendor_identifier, payment 
FROM jsonapple 
GROUP BY unique_vendor_identifier, payment) A group by unique_vendor_identifier
```

**TABLA**

```
CREATE TABLE `jsonapple` (
  `id` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latest_receipt` varchar(8000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_purchase_date_pst` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unique_vendor_identifier` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_purchase_date_ms` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expires_date_formatted` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_in_intro_offer_period` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchase_date_ms` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expires_date_formatted_pst` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_trial_period` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unique_identifier` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_transaction_id` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expires_date` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_item_id` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_id` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bvrs` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `web_order_line_item_id` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version_external_identifier` bigint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchase_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchase_date_pst` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_purchase_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `environment` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_renew_status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_renew_product_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notification_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_code` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `traffic_source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiration_intent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_in_billing_retry_period` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acquisition_campaign` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: seria interesante que nos expliques que hace el query 1 y el 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale creé la estructura, le metí datos y al final esta es mi query:

```
SELECT
    jsonapple.unique_vendor_identifier,
    sum(jsonapple.payment) AS total_pagos_vendor,
    max(jsonapple.id) AS ultimo_payment_vendor
FROM
    jsonapple
GROUP BY
    jsonapple.unique_vendor_identifier
ORDER BY
    ultimo_payment_vendor DESC
```

lo que he hecho es sumar los totales, agrupando por unique_vendor_identifiery además he seleccionado el ultimo id de pago de corresponiente a cada unique_vendor_identifier para luego ordenar de forma descendente por ese "campo".

Comment: Gracias Juan Luis!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  jsonapple.unique_vendor_identifier, SUM(
  SELECT jsonapple.payment 
  FROM jsonapple 
  GROUP BY
  jsonapple.unique_vendor_identifier
) AS total_pagos_vendor
FROM jsonapple
ORDER_BY jsonapple.id DESC
```

No lo he probado porque no tengo las tablas, pero creo que es esto:
Primero seleccionas el unique_vendor_identifier y el sumatorio de todos los payments agrupados por unique_vendor_identifier. 
Después lo ordenas todo por id descendente y así tendrás la suma de todos los payments de cada vendor, ordenados por id (del payment supongo)

Te quedaría la tabla así:

```
unique_vendor_identifier | total_pagos_vendor
```

No puedo concretar más de cabeza, podría darte algún error, si es así, comentalo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, corri el query y me tira un error, te paso. Gracias!                                                                                                         You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT jsonapple.payment 
  FROM jsonapple 
  GROUP BY
  jsonapple.unique_vendor' at line 2

Comment: para poder probar la query, me haría falta la estructura de la tabla tal cual es

Comment: Gracias Juan Luis, te paso la estructura.